# Node.Js express it always redircts to root

Tags: node.js, express

Untill yester day, It works very well. however, at this morning I run this project by using npm start, It doesn't work.
The code is below:

```
router.get('/manage', (req, res) => {
    if (res.data.manager != 1) { res.redirect('/'); return; }
    
    res.db.getTeamUrlPairs((teams) => {
        res.render("manageTeam", { 
            teams: teams ,
            data: res.data
        })
    })
})
```

When I connect to /manage, it just redirect to '/' although res.data.manager was 1.
So, I tried to change the circumstance such as routing url, inner code.
But, I changed it to:

```
router.get('/manage', (req, res) => {
    res.send('hello');
})
```

It doesn't work. I mean, the change not reflected. I've restarted my computer, close my vscode, stop and re-run npm. it always just redirect to root.

What can I do for this?

Ps. Other routings are working well... what the hell is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the differences between `app.get()` and `app.use()` methods:

`app.get(<registered_path>, <middleware>)` is triggered only on GET requests that have an ***exact match*** to the registered_path.

`app.use(<registered_path>, <middleware>)` is triggered for all HTTP methods (POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE) where the URL path of the request ***start with*** the registered_path.

***The order in which you specify your middleware's is important.***
If we registered the following middlewares:

```
app.use('/', <middleware1>)
```

and

```
app.get('/manage', <middleware2>)
```

The request to **/manage** will never trigger middleware2 (unless you called the `next()` function in `middleware1`).

Also, consider using breakpoints in each of your middleware's to see what middleware is actually triggered when you send an HTTP request to **/manage**.

Answer (score 0):

Routing order is important.

```
router.get('/:a',(req,res)=>{})
router.get('/manage', (req,res)=>{})
```

This code won't work well. specifically manage doesn't work.
However, below:

```
router.get('/manage', (req,res)=>{}) 
router.get('/:a',(req,res)=>{})
```

does work well.